# What foundational axiomatic system should I use for a proof of either P=NP, P != NP, or its undecidability?

Tags: computer-science, axioms

I am aware of foundational axiomatic systems for mathematics such as ZFC, though I am unsure which to use / which would be accepted as underpinning foundational axioms of which P=NP, P!=NP, or it's undecidability, could be proven. For instance, if I just came up with my own axioms that do not stem from a foundational system (that I'm aware of using), it becomes almost trivial to prove that P!=NP, at least in my experience (I could be fooling myself here).

***I would like to pick axioms that the mathematics community would largely accept as reasonable (or, at least, better my chances of that), and I think I may need an appropriate foundational system of which my axioms can be founded upon.***

I understand the difficulty of this problem to the degree that I know I will most likely not solve it, however, I'd be remiss if I didn't give it a try and get familiar with the intricacies of it. So, please, no comments on that.

Please point out the flaws in my questioning here.

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is the standard for everything. There are some times where we want to use a different system, but the default one is $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Moreover, there are technical results like **Shoenfield absoluteness** which say that things like the axiom of choice or the continuum hypothesis **cannot** affect things like $\mathsf{P\not=NP}$. In particular, if $\mathsf{P\not=NP}$ is independent of $\mathsf{ZF}$ it's also independent of $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$.

Comment: (That said, already a proof of independence from first-order Peano arithmetic, or even the very weak arithmetic theory $I\Sigma_1$, would already be one of the most significant results in complexity theory to date.)

Comment: Really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: A successful proof in any of the main proof assistants (such as Coq, Lean, HOL, etc.) would be more than acceptable. Many proof assistants use the Calculus of Constructions, which is a type theory.